# How to resolve `pyenv` issue installing Python < 3.7 in macbook pro with intel-chip and Big Sur?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pyenv

`pyenv` seems to have issues on a Macbook with intel-chip and Big Sur.

Here's my system information:

```
$ brew --version
3.2.2

$ brew list
==> Formulae
autoconf    gdbm        mpdecimal   pkg-config  python@3.9  sqlite      xz
bzip2       m4      openssl@1.1 pyenv       readline    tcl-tk      zlib

$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 12.5.1
Build version 12E507

$ xcode-select -version
xcode-select version 2384.

$ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.4
BuildVersion:   20F71
```

Here's what happens when I try to install various `pyenv` versions:

```
$ pyenv install 3.9.6   # Success
$ pyenv install 3.8.11  # Success
$ pyenv install 3.7.11  # Success
$ pyenv install 3.6.14  # Error
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.4 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/qr/wfhlfnfs62g7lf56wpk1ffp80000gp/T/python-build.20210715170801.48468
Results logged to /var/folders/qr/wfhlfnfs62g7lf56wpk1ffp80000gp/T/python-build.20210715170801.48468.log

Last 10 log lines:
        ret = sendfile(in, out, offset, &sbytes, &sf, flags);
              ^
./Modules/posixmodule.c:10432:5: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
    Py_FatalError("abort() called from Python code didn't abort!");
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include   -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include   -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wstrict-prototypes   -I. -I./Include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/Users/ranjan.lamichhane/.pyenv/versions/3.6.14/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/Users/ranjan.lamichhane/.pyenv/versions/3.6.14/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/pwdmodule.c -o Modules/pwdmodule.o
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [Modules/posixmodule.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 warning generated.
```

I have tried to fix it with suggestion found in some github issue threads but nothing seems to work.

Comment: rrlamichhane, any luck? I'm also facing the same issue although my build is the latest updated one. I've tried all the suggestions I found and nothing seems to work

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found any solution yet. I've just been using Python version > 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem while installing python 3.7.6 both with brew and pyenv.
Running the following command fixed the problem:
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib" pyenv install --patch 3.7.6 < <(curl -sSL [https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch%5C?full_index%5C=1))